# How to handle if a user forgets its username django

Tags: django, django-users

Is there a way to implement a method that if a user forgot its username(since it is used for login) he can get it through email?
I have seen ways to reset password but I do not want user to reset its username but only get that through email.

Comment: https://github.com/brutasse/django-password-reset or look at the code how they implemented it . :-)

Comment: This is a good but too broad question. Have you tried anything that we could build on?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication Completely followed this tutorial for password reset functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well it is possible he must insert his email in a field which is in a form that leads to `GetUsername()`

then you post to a `GetUsername()`

```
def GetUsername(request):
   user = User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])
   print(user.get_username())
   text = 'Hello, %s \n your username is %s'.format(user.first_name, user.get_username())
   html =  '<h3>Hello, %s<h/3><br><p> your username is %s<p>'.format(user.first_name, user.get_username())
   SendEmail(text, html, 'Reminding your username', user.email)
```

If you have a SMTP sever you can send your email like that

```
def SendEmail(text, html, subject, to):
    email = MIMEMultipart('alternative')    
    email["Subject"] = ENV + subject
    email["From"] = 'noreply@yourdomain.com'

    email["To"] = to

    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')#plain text
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')#htmp style text
    email.attach(part1)
    email.attach(part2)
    s = smtplib.SMTP('192.168.2.1:25')#this is your server SMTP
    s.send_message(email)
    s.quit()
```

If you don't have SMTP server on your own you can use gmail

[you can check the reference here](https://medium.com/@_christopher/how-to-send-emails-with-python-django-through-google-smtp-server-for-free-22ea6ea0fb8e)

Comment: You should always use [`get_username()` instead of referencing the username attribute directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_username).

Comment: Actually no I have not created a sendEmail function can you tell me how to? I was following https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication tutorial so checking mail on command window for now

Comment: Updated @Ahmed check it out hope it helps you

Comment: Thankyou so much, it was so helpful now everything is working perfectly.